# Get equivalent classes in order

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I need to get equivalent classes of an OWL Class in the same order as in the .owl file.

I use this code

```
for(OWLClassExpression cls: clazz.getEquivalentClasses(ontology) ) { 

Set <OWLClass> classes_of_the_Expression =cls.getClassesInSignature();
}
```

But this code gets them randomly.

Please find below an example of cases I treat. Here, dog_owner class is an equivalent Class and intersection of both person and dog classes. By executing my java code I get first dog class, then person class; and I need to get the inverse which means person class then dog class. Because I need precisely the first class of the equivalent classes.

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peopleeemodifiée#dog_owner">
<owl:equivalentClass>
  <owl:Class>
    <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
      <owl:Class rdf:about="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peopleeemodifiée#person"/>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peopleeemodifiée#has_pet"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
        <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peopleeemodifiée#dog"/>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:intersectionOf>
  </owl:Class>
</owl:equivalentClass>
<rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
>dog owner</rdfs:label>
<rdfs:comment rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
></rdfs:comment>
```

Comment: I am guessing the version of OWLAPI you're using is 3.5. OWLClass objects are comparable, so you can add them to a list and sort the list reliably, however there is no support for respecting the order of input OWL files. OWL does not specify a mandatory order for equivalent classes.

Why do you need to refer exactly the first element?

Comment: I need it because I have to add a subclass axiom linking the general class ( in the example below: dog_owner  with the first class of the intersection which is:  person. So, I need to add automatically (using a script) the axiom :     <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peopleee#person"/>    but not this one :   <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peopleee#dog"/> that is my objective

Comment: I add them first to a list, I thought by doing this, I'll keep the order, but unfortunately, the function clazz.getClassesInSignature(); get them in disorder

Comment: That can't be achieved without a better way to select the classes you're after. Do you mean the named class in the intersection? Person is a named class but dog is part of an anonymous restriction.

Comment: So, there is a way to return just the class Not the anonymous restriction?  exactly, I need just the named class ( person in the example )

Comment: I'll add an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to only take into account the named classes inside an intersection included in an equivalent classes axiom, you can use visitors:

```
OWLEquivalentClassesAxiom ax=null;
ax.accept(new OWLObjectVisitor() {
    @Override
    public void visit(OWLObjectIntersectionOf ce) {
        ce.operands().filter(x->x.isOWLClass()).forEach(x->{
            // this is where x is Person, or any other 
            // named class in the intersection;
            // anonymous classes are skipped
        });
    }
});
```

For OWLAPI 3:

```
for(OWLClass clazzzz : ontology.getClassesInSignature()) {
    for(OWLEquivalentClassesAxiom ax: ontology.getEquivalentClassesAxioms(clazzzz)) {
        OWLObjectVisitorAdapter visitor = new OWLObjectVisitorAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void visit(OWLObjectIntersectionOf ce) {
            for (OWLClassExpression e : ce.getOperands()) {
                if (!e.isAnonymous()) {
                    // this is where x is Person, or any other
                    // named class in the intersection;
                    // anonymous classes are skipped
                }
            }
        }
        };
        ax.accept(visitor);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the way I can use this code, I've never used visitors before. Please, can you help me more. Must my class extend another class or implement an interface?  because the function accept for ax is unknown when I add your code into my java class

Comment: Which version of owl api are you using? My code is written with owl api 5

Comment: I have OWL API 3

Comment: I tried it, but it generates an exception which concerns the ax: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException... I think ax must be initialized but how?

Comment: You need to select the equivalent classes axioms from the ontology or from a reasoner, same as you'd do in your previous code.

Comment: I still can't use your code to have just the named classes inside an intersection included in an equivalent classes axiom. Please, can you give me a concrete example. I'll put the version I'm working on below

Comment: Thank you Ignazio for your help. Finally, It works. That's just what I need

Answer (score 1):

Try org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLNaryBooleanClassExpression#**getOperandsAsList** method or its stream companion.

Please note: OWL is RDF. RDF does not support ordering by design and by definition. Although you use "signature" method, it should not return ordered data due to these general reasons (and it seems that's why it is Set).

But right part of owl:intersectionOf is a rdf:List, it is always ordered, so there should be something to retrieve ordered information from right part of n-ary class-expression.

Code example of usage:

```
            String s = "<rdf:RDF\n" +
            "    xmlns:rdf=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#\"\n" +
            "    xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\"\n" +
            "    xmlns:owl=\"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#\"\n" +
            "    xmlns:rdfs=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#\"\n" +
            "    xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#\">\n" +
            "  <owl:Ontology/>\n" +
            "  <owl:Class rdf:about=\"http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peopleeemodifiée#dog_owner\">\n" +
            "    <rdfs:comment></rdfs:comment>\n" +
            "    <rdfs:label>dog owner</rdfs:label>\n" +
            "    <owl:equivalentClass>\n" +
            "      <owl:Class>\n" +
            "        <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType=\"Collection\">\n" +
            "          <owl:Class rdf:about=\"http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peopleeemodifiée#person\"/>\n" +
            "          <owl:Restriction>\n" +
            "            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource=\"http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peopleeemodifiée#dog\"/>\n" +
            "            <owl:onProperty>\n" +
            "              <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about=\"http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peopleeemodifiée#has_pet\"/>\n" +
            "            </owl:onProperty>\n" +
            "          </owl:Restriction>\n" +
            "        </owl:intersectionOf>\n" +
            "      </owl:Class>\n" +
            "    </owl:equivalentClass>\n" +
            "  </owl:Class>\n" +
            "</rdf:RDF>";

    OWLOntology ontology;
    try (InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        ontology = OntManagers.createONT().loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(in);
    }
    System.out.println("========");
    OWLEquivalentClassesAxiom equivalentClassesAxiom = ontology.axioms(AxiomType.EQUIVALENT_CLASSES).findFirst().orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    OWLObjectIntersectionOf anon = equivalentClassesAxiom.classExpressions()
            .filter(e -> ClassExpressionType.OBJECT_INTERSECTION_OF.equals(e.getClassExpressionType()))
            .map(OWLObjectIntersectionOf.class::cast)
            .findFirst().orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    System.out.println(anon.getOperandsAsList().get(0)); // <-- always person
    System.out.println(anon.getOperandsAsList().get(1)); // <-- always anon ObjectSomeValuesFrom
    System.out.println(OWLObjectSomeValuesFrom.class.cast(anon.getOperandsAsList().get(1)).getFiller()); // <--always dog
```

Comment: Just as a comment: `getOperandsAsList` doesn't necessarily return the order of the document. It uses an OWL API specific ordering of the class expressions in a SortedSet (resp. Stream in OWL API 5), see the [code](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version5/impl/src/main/java/uk/ac/manchester/cs/owl/owlapi/OWLNaryBooleanClassExpressionImpl.java#L39)